# Is is possible to use "web RTC" as a WP plugin?

Tags: wordpress, webrtc

I want to create a plugin with web RTC for WP.
Is it comfortable to make? or there is any other way of making a video plugin easily? Is there any expert in this field?

Comment: See https://github.com/ossrs/WordPress-Plugin-SrsPlayer

Answer (score 1):

Webrtc is an open project that enables browsers with real time communication capabilities. 
Wordpress is a content management system.

Webrtc functionalities are browser dependent( with most modern browsers supporting it except safari). It is possible to create webrtc plugin for wordpress as wordpress plugin is just a program or a set of functions written in PHP.

In the plugin you just need to first check whether the browser supports webrtc or not. If it supports webrtc then you just need to provide signalling, create peer connection and register the webrtc events handlers like onicecandidate, onaddstream.

THE WEBRTC API: 
It consists of a few main javascript objects −

- RTCPeerConnection: It helps us connect to peers, initialize connections and attach media streams. It also manages a UDP connection with another user.
- MediaStreamRTC :
  There are three key points of functionality −
  1.It gives a developer access to a streamobject that represent video and audio streams
  2.It manages the selection of input user devices in case a user has multiple cameras or microphones on his device
  3.It provides a security level asking user all the time he wants to fetch s stream
- DataChannel : you may send additional data using DataChannel API.

You can learn more about webrtc at this link [webrtc peer connection tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_rtcpeerconnection_apis.htm) ,
[webrtc media stream tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_media_stream_apis.htm) and [webrtc Data channel tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_rtcdatachannel_apis.htm)

There are already many webrtc plugins for wordpress--- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wprtc-real-time-video-for-wp/